# Pass unknown number of parameters to Visualforce JavaScript Remoting

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

Is there a way to pass an unknown number of parameters to Visualforce JavaScript Remoting like:

```
remoting('getExampleData', arg1, arg2, arg3)

function remoting(target, ...args) {
    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        configSettings.remoteActions[target],
        args,
        function (result, event) {
            if (event.status)
                console.log(result);
        },
        { escape: false }
    );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass unknown number of parameters to Visualforce JavaScript Remoting, but you can use wrapper-object like a parameter and this object can contains all your required data. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/afawcett/5091009) for more details.

Also you can manually serialize all your required parameters to single string and pass it as one parameter, and then deserialize it on server side.